# C*-algebras with bizzarre structure of projections

Tags: c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

This is probably well-known to the experts but I could not find any answer neither in my head nor in the literature: Is there a (unital) C*-algebra such that its projections do not form a lattice (under the usual ordering)? Certainly, this cannot be a von Neumann algebra.

Comment: If you look at the universal representation of the C* algebra and then  consider the double commutant of its image you get the enveloping von Neumann algebra. The question of whether the projections in the C* algebra form a sublattice of the enveloping von Neumann algebra is considered here: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601003. I hope this helps!

Comment: Probably I should ask this under the pseudonym unknown(Google) to spare myself embarrassment, but...
$$
$$
Are there examples among the commutative `$C^*$` algebras; i.e., $C(K)$ spaces?

Comment: Bill, in the arxiv paper linked by Jon it is said (and proved) that a commutative $C^*$-algebra has always the lattice property (see the beginning of Sect. 4).

Comment: Thanks, Valerio.  But I was just being stupid, thinking of contractive projections on $C(K)$ instead of in $C(K)$.  In the commutative case projections are just indicator functions of clopen sets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find examples of AF algebras without the lattice property in Section 2 of *AF Algebras with a Lattice of Projections* by Aldo J. Lazar [here](http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=2618).

Comment: Perfect! I was just commenting that in that arxiv paper there were only examples of C^*$-algebras with that property and not without :)

Answer (score 18):

Here is perhaps the simplest example.  Let $A$ be the C*-algebra of all sequences of $2 \times 2$ matrices converging to a scalar multiple of diag(1,0).  Let $p$ be the constant sequence diag(1,0), and $q$ a sequence of rank 1 projections converging to diag(1,0) but never exactly equal.  Then $p$ and $q$ have no upper bound at all.  This example can be tweaked to make it unital by allowing any limit matrix at infinity and taking $q$ to alternate diag(1,0) and nearby but unequal projections.  Then $p$ and $q$ have no least upper bound.